# C# Telegram v16.0 проблема с загрузкой файлов

Tags: c#, .net, telegram-bot, api

Проблема возникает при попытке загрузить отправленый боту файл. Файл создан, но он пустой. Помогите решить проблему

```
bot = new(id);
bot.OnMessage += OnMessage;
bot.OnMessage += OnFileMessage;
bot.StartReceiving();
```

Метод для обработки файловых сообщений:

```
private static async void OnFileMessage(object? sender, MessageEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Message.Type != Telegram.Bot.Types.Enums.MessageType.Text && e.Message.Caption != null && e.Message.Caption.Contains("!download "))
    {
        string path = e.Message.Caption.Replace("!download ", "");

        StreamWriter stream = new(path, true);
        await bot.GetInfoAndDownloadFileAsync(e.Message.Document.FileId, stream.BaseStream);
    }
}
```

Результат:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Новый созданый файл пустой.

Comment: Вижу поток, не вижу его закрытия.

Comment: Спасибо большое!

Comment: `using StreamWriter stream = ...`

Answer (score 0):

Нужно было закрыть поток.

```
StreamWriter stream = new(path);
await bot.GetInfoAndDownloadFileAsync(e.Message.Document.FileId, stream.BaseStream);
stream.Close();
```

Comment: Почитайте про `Dispose`, ибо порой достаточно сделать просто `using StreamWriter stream = new(path);` (или `using (StreamWriter stream = new(path)){ код записи } другой код работы с закрытым файлом`

Comment: Уберите 3 строчку, а в первой допишите в самом начале `using`.